# HyperV Get-VM on remote host works in console, but not when running script

Tags: powershell, hyper-v, powershell-remoting

I have a script that checks on the health of VMs on a long list of hosts - and it works for MOST hosts.
We run this script from a domain server and it checks domain hosts - and most hosts respond properly.  A few hosts return a "you do not have permission" error.

Investigating, I found that if I log on as the user that runs the script, and open a powershell ISE As Admin console and run the "Get-VM -computer RemoteHost1", it works just fine.  However, no matter how I run the script - normal or elevated - when running the script, the same host gives a "you do not have permission" error - and  it makes no sense.  Most hosts are responding fine either way I run it - command or script.  I can't find any permission differences between hosts that would cause this.

I've looked at the powershell version on the host, added the user specifically to the administrators group and the hyperv administrators group, etc.

If I open the script in an ISE console and run it - works.  If I right click the script and run with powershell, some get permission denied, some don't. If I run the script using an elevated scheduled task, some get permission denied - most don't.

EDIT:
I have given up on getting this to work and have used Connectwise Control to run the powershell script locally on the server(s) having issues with the remote commands, works fine that way.  We just get a email for each server instead of one report.

Comment: This may be a Group Policy Issue.  I usually like using a file explorer to see see  if I have permissions to the remote machine.  I use \\machine-name\ and then see if I can find folder and open files.

Comment: UNC works fine - Get-VM works in an ISE as administrator window - but just when run via the script in any way, it fails on a few, not all hosts.

Comment: The documentations says Get-VM says it gets it from VM Center Server. So error indicates you do not have VM Center Server installed in machines or you have different version.  See : https://developer.vmware.com/docs/powercli/latest/vmware.vimautomation.core/commands/get-vm/#Default

Comment: Well, JD, they are not VmWare, they are Hyper-V, and the command works on the server itself and several other servers that have hyper-v installed, the issue is with using the command from a remote server as a scheduled task.  IE, we have 20 Hyper-V hosts and using Get-VM remotely from a central server gets results fine on 15 of them, but gets a permission denied on the other 5.

Comment: I'm not an expert on the differences of Virtual Machines.  From documentations, Get-VM  returns the Virtual Machines and Hyper-V is one type of virtual machine. From web : vCenter Multi-Hypervisor Manager is an installable vCenter Server component that lets you manage heterogeneous virtual environments. After you install and configure vCenter Multi-Hypervisor Manager, you can use the vSphere Client to manage both VMware and third-party hypervisors such as Microsoft Hyper-V.

Comment: See troubleshooting : https://www.altaro.com/vmware/two-factor-authentication-vcenter/?force_isolation=true